# How can i Encrypt MD5 to variable?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, md5

At the moment i am Trying to grab a password from a database that is encrypted in MD5. E.G:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (1001, "Smith", "J.", "Alan", 'Mr', "43 The Glebe", "Mugwell Hill", "Nodnol", "", "N10 4SB", MD5("Alan"), "Mugwell Hill");
```

the password in this case being Alan.
i am trying compare the password that is being input by the user.

```
String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Erehwon","root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Customer where customer_number='" + userid + "' and passwd ='" + pwd + "'");

if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
    //out.println("welcome " + userid);
    //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
} else {
    out.println("Invalid password <a href='login_page.jsp'>try again</a>");
    out.println(pwd);
    out.println(userid);

}
```

As you can probably tell this is coming through invalid password because the input value is not in MD5 format. Is there anyway that i can convert the password into MD5 or Decrypt the database password so that they match?

Comment: ```"select * from Customer where customer_number='" + userid + "' and passwd = MD5('" + pwd + "')")``` just wrap that pwd in MD5();

Answer (score 0):

1. You **can't extract** the **password** from the hash. 
   This is not possible because many passwords can have the same MD5. Imagine that you have the MD5 for a 1GB file. This would be a very good compression, but it isn't because you cannot restore the initial information. Hashing is not encryption.
2. You can compare the hashes:

   - see [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) to obtain the MD5:

     ```
     MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(yourString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
     ```